# Downloading and setting a keyserver with apt-key adv fails with gpg: keyserver receive failed: General error

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg, apt

`apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key <key>`

gives

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.t7lwaQiAFD/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key <key>
gpg: keyserver receive failed: General error
```

This was working before.
I've even tried changing the keyserver, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `hkps` protocol,

`apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key <key>`

and let it figure out the protocol by itself.